# Scrapy: adding a variable to xpath array

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I just wanted to know if there is a way on how I will be able to add num to tr[1] like 
this -> tr[1+num]... I tried tr[1+9] and it worked but when i changed it to num, of course it gave me an error. Thanks!

```
    items = []
    num = 1
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    dir = hxs.select('/html/body/div/table')
    for i, tr in enumerate(hxs.select('/html/body/div/table//tr[count(./td)=2]')):
        if (i % 7 == 0): 
            if (i > 0): items.append(item)
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        idx = i % 7
        if(idx == 0):
            item[rn[idx]] = tr.select('./td[2]//text()').extract()[0]
            item ["title"] = dir.select('//tr[num]/td[2]/b/text()').extract()
            num = num + 9
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: give the xpath as `select('//tr[%s]/td[2]/b/text()'%str(num))`

Comment: list index out of range. the only problem for me is the tr[num] since tr[1+9] works...

Comment: i should put it as the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the xpath as `select('//tr[%s]/td[2]/b/text()'%str(num))`

`num` is a variable and num inside `''` does not make any sense

Comment: :) SO is a nice place. I too have learned scrapy and selenium for web scraping last month